# What is causing 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error?

Tags: vb.net, csv, foreach

What is causing 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' error? It can't be my file, defianetly not. Below is my code:

```
 Sub pupiltest()

    Dim exitt As String = Console.ReadLine
    Do
        If IsNumeric(exitt) Then
            Exit Do
        Else
           'error message
        End If
    Loop

    Select Case exitt
        Case 1
        Case 2
        Case 3
    End Select

    Do
        If exitt = 1 Then
            pupilmenu()
        ElseIf exitt = 3 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    Dim score As Integer
    Dim word As String
    Dim totalscore As Integer = 0

    'If DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Today) = 5 Then
    'Else
    '    Console.WriteLine("You are only allowed to take the test on Friday unless you missed it")
    '    pupiltest()
    'End If

    Dim founditem() As String = Nothing
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
        Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
        founditem = item
    Next

    Dim stdntfname As String = founditem(3)
    Dim stdntsname As String = founditem(4)
    Dim stdntyear As String = founditem(5)
    Console.Clear()

    If founditem IsNot Nothing Then
        Do
            If stdntyear = founditem(5) And daytoday = founditem(6) Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf daytoday <> founditem(6) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry you are not allowed to do this test today. Test available on " & item(6).Substring(0, 3) & "/" & item(6).Substring(3, 6) & "/" & item(6).Substring(6, 9))
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)
                pupiltest()
            ElseIf stdntyear <> founditem(5) Then
                Console.WriteLine("Year not found, please contact the system analysts")
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(2500)
                pupiltest()
            End If
        Loop
    End If

    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\testtests.csv")
        Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
        Dim mine As String = String.Join(",", item(2), item(3), item(4), item(5), item(6))
        For i As Integer = 1 To 10
            Console.WriteLine(i.ToString & "." & item(1))
            Console.Write("Please enter the word: ")
            word = Console.ReadLine
            If word = Nothing Or word <> item(0) Then
                score += 0
            ElseIf word = item(0) Then
                score += 2
            ElseIf word = mine Then
                score += 1
            End If
        Next

        If score > 15 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Well done! Your score is" & score & "/20")
        ElseIf score > 10 Then
            Console.WriteLine("Your score is" & score & "/20")
        ElseIf score Then
        End If
    Next

    Using sw As New StreamWriter("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdntscores", True)
        sw.Write(stdntfname, stdntsname, stdntyear, score, daytoday, item(7))
        Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error accessing designated file")
        End Try
    End Using



    End
End Sub
```

All help is highly appreciated,

Comment: Can you show us more of the code, possibly the entire subroutine for this particular code snippet.

Comment: What are you doing with that item() array or foundItem() array?

Comment: The exception tells you exactly which line is causing the problem. Which one is it?

Comment: I've repeated the lines just to by pass the stack overflow regulations.

Comment: @Ed. No need to be doing that... I edited the post and removed the duplicate lines.

Comment: @Dayan Otherwise it wouldn't let me post since 'It's mostly code'.

Comment: I'd wager the issue is with `item(6)` or `founditem(6)`. Are you sure each line of your csv files has 7 items? If you are getting an error you should post the error, not sure why you are withholding that information.

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Ed. That is just the error message, post the entire Stacktrace. if need be, wrap the entire content of that subroutine in a `try/catch` block to catch the exception, then you can get more information on what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You are constantly replacing the `foundItem` array when you  do `founditem = item`:

```
Dim founditem() As String = Nothing
    For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
        Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
        founditem = item
    Next
```

Also, you are using (**=**) the assignment operation instead of (**==**) relational operator, to compare. Refer to [this article](http://zetcode.com/lang/visualbasic/operators/) for help in understanding the difference between the two.

Instead of this: `If stdntyear = founditem(5) And daytoday = founditem(6) Then`

Use this: `If (stdntyear == founditem(5)) And (daytoday == founditem(6)) Then`

Now back to your main error. You continue to assign the `item`array to `founditem` every time you iterate (Which overwrites previous content). At the end of the `Iteration` you will be left with the last entry in your CSV only... So in other words, `founditem` will only have 1 element inside of it. If you try to pick out ANYTHING but index **0**, it will throw the exception `index was outside the bounds of the array`

So when you try to do the following later, it throws the exception.

```
 Dim stdntfname As String = founditem(3) 'index 3 does not exist!
```

**To fix it do the following change:**

```
Dim founditem() As String = Nothing
For Each line As String In File.ReadAllLines("F:\Computing\Spelling Bee\stdnt&staffdtls.csv")
    'NOTE: Make sure you know exactly how many columns your csv has or whatever column
    '      you wish to access. 
    Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)
    founditem(0) = item(0) 'Assign item index 0 to index 0 of founditem...
    founditem(1) = item(1)
    founditem(2) = item(2)
    founditem(3) = item(3)
    founditem(4) = item(4)
    founditem(5) = item(5) 
    founditem(6) = item(6) 
Next
```

For more help on how to work with VB.NET `Arrays` visit this site: http://www.dotnetperls.com/array-vbnet

Comment: Sorry, there should we a 'Exit For' after founditem = item

Comment: Now I receive this, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Ed. Well that's a whole new problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your line `Dim item() As String = line.Split(","c)` there's no guarantee that the correct number of elements exist. It's possible that one of the lines is missing a comma or is a blank trailing line in the document. You might want to add a `If item.Length >= 7` and skipping rows that don't have the right number of rows. Also, remember that unlike VB6, arrays in .Net are 0 based not 1 based so make sure that item(6) is the value that you think it is.